# octave: using find() on cell array {} subscript and assigning it to another cell array

Tags: octave

This is an example in Section 6.3.1 Comma Separated Lists Generated from Cell Arrays of the Octave documentation (I browsed it through the `doc` command on the Octave prompt) which I don't quite understand.

```
in{1} = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];
in{2} = inf;
in{3} = "last";
in{4} = "first";
out = cell(4, 1);
[out{1:3}] = find(in{1 : 3}); % line which I do not understand
```

So at the end of this section, we have `in` looking like:

```
in =
{
  [1,1] =
     10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
  [1,2] = Inf
  [1,3] = last
  [1,4] = first
}
```

and `out` looking like:

```
out =
{
  [1,1] =
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  [2,1] =
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  [3,1] =
    10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
  [4,1] = [](0x0)
}
```

Here, `find` is called with 3 output parameters (forgive me if I'm wrong on calling them output parameters, I am pretty new to Octave) from `[out{1:3}]`, which represents the first 3 empty cells of the cell array `out`.

When I run `find(in{1 : 3})` with 3 output parameters, as in:

```
[i,j,k] = find(in{1 : 3})
```

I get:

```
i = 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
j = 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
k = 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

which kind of explains why `out` looks like it does, but when I execute `in{1:3}`, I get:

```
ans = 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
ans = Inf
ans = last
```

which are the 1st to 3rd elements of the `in` cell array.

My question is: Why does `find(in{1 : 3})` drop off the 2nd and 3rd entries in the comma separated list for `in{1 : 3}`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/find.html) for `find` should help you answer your question:

When called with 3 output arguments, `find` returns the row and column indices of non-zero elements (that's your `i` and `j`) and a vector containing the non-zero values (that's your `k`). That explains the 3 output arguments, but not why it only considers `in{1}`. To answer that you need to look at what happens when you pass 3 input arguments to `find` as in `find (x, n, direction)`:

> If three inputs are given, *direction* should be one of "first" or
>   "last", requesting only the first or last *n* indices, respectively.
>   However, the indices are always returned in ascending order.

so `in{1}` is your `x` (your data if you want), `in{2}` is how many indices `find` should consider (all of them in your case since `in{2} = Inf`) and `{in3}`is whether `find` should find the first or last indices of the vector `in{1}` (last in your case).